# call onClick on a button on a different layout

Tags: android

I'm working on a application where I have a list view. The list view has a button which is on different layout file. How can I call the button from my activity? I've tried adding that xml file to my activity but the setOnClickListener doesn't seems to work.

This is how my xml file looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/objectiveOtherAddedEditText"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addOtherObjectiveTextBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is where I want to call it:

```
public class VisitObjectiveFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String TITLE = "Visit Objective";
SQLiteDatabase database;
SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;

public static VisitObjectiveFragment newInstance() {

    return new VisitObjectiveFragment();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_visit_objective, container, false);
    final View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.other_objective_list_view, container, false);


    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_objective);
    ImageButton buttonAdd = (ImageButton) view1.findViewById(R.id.addOtherObjectiveTextBox);

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you mean the other layout is for the adapter that is being used to inflate each row of the list view?

Comment: The id you mentioned in `ImageButton buttonAdd = (ImageButton) view1.findViewById(R.id.addOtherObjectiveTextBox);` is nowhere to be found in the XML. The XML ID you mentioned in the ImageButton is `android:id="@+id/addNewOtherObjectiveTextBox"`

Comment: @AnindyaDutta, Precisely. All I have is a list view that inflates two different layouts. One layout has checkboxes and the other one just has an input box with an image button with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {}` inside your adapter class. If you don`t have one. Create it

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `<include></include>` tag to specify the xml inside your parent xml

Answer (score 0):

you should add inflated object to your main view

```
public class VisitObjectiveFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String TITLE = "Visit Objective";
SQLiteDatabase database;
SQLiteOpenHelper dbHelper;

public static VisitObjectiveFragment newInstance() {

    return new VisitObjectiveFragment();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_visit_objective, container, false);
    final View view1 = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.other_objective_list_view, null);


    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_objective);
    ImageButton buttonAdd = (ImageButton) view1.findViewById(R.id.addNewOtherObjectiveTextBox);

    view.addView(buttonAdd);

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is create callback interface. See the official documentation (link below) https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
It allow you to communicate between fragment-activity.